# Can setters modify non-writable/non-configurable properties?

Tags: javascript, oop, getter-setter

I have been reading about property attributes (configurable, writable, enumerable) and am looking for some clarification on how setters interact with non-writable / non-configurable properties.

Specifically, if a property is defined using `Object.defineProperty()`, it will default to `configurable: false` and `writable: false`. In this case, would a setter function within the same object still be able to modify the value of the property?

This is the example that I'm looking at:

```
var book = {};

Object.defineProperties(book, {
    _year: {
        value: 2004
    },
    edition: {
        value: 1
    },
    year: {
        get: function(){
            return this._year;
        },
        set: function(newValue){
            if (newValue > 2004) {
                this._year = newValue;
                this.edition += newValue - 2004;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

-- From "Professional JavaScript for Web Developers, 3rd Ed." (Nicholas C Zakas)

So, the setter part of `book.year` is meant to update the value of `book._year`.

But since `book._year` is defined using `Object.defineProperty` and not explicitly set to be either writable or configurable, shouldn't not be modifiable? Or are functions within the same object (ie `book.year`) somehow excluded from those restrictions?

It is also worth noting that this code gives me some funny results when I run it in the browser... Namely: 
`book.year = 2005` does nothing to either `book.year` or `book._year`, and
`book.year(2005)` results in `TypeError: book.year is not a function`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no exclusions about `writable` true/false for self properties. If you have a non `writable` property then there is no way to change from wherever you wanted to do it. Except for configurable values when you can change descriptor to writable.

Another issue about TypeError: 
setter function in property definition using `defineProperty` is a hidden method that invokes when you assign the property. That's not an actual function from outside.

[image: You can see it's execution by debugging when you assign a value to this property]

Comment: Could you clarify a bit, or send me to your source for the "there are no exclusions" part of your answer? I'm still not clear on why the setter in the example is (supposedly) able to change the non-writable `_year` or why I get a TypeError when I try to run the code.

Comment: I mean that you can change a non-writable property only changing `writable: false` to `writable: true` if it is configurable. There is no other way to change this kind of property. I made a screenshot as earlier to show, that when setter is executing with value of `3005` then `this._year` is assigning, but nothing writes, (`this._year = 3005` doesn't work because it is non-writable), so you cannot write anything to this property. About your error: set, get function are a hidden functions, they are executing when you assign a value, like `book.year = 3005'

Comment: then setter function is invoking. 'year` a property, not a method, so you get an error

Comment: So, you're saying that the example is faulty -- the given code doesn't actually provide a way to change `this._year`. Is that right?